# Create sublists by splitting list at a value

Tags: python, list, split, sublist

I have a really long list. Below is an excerpt from it.

```
['1',  '15943882',  '63',  '1',  '-9',  '-9',  '-9',  '-27',  '1',  '145',  
 '1',  '233',  '-9',  '50',  '20',  '1',  '0',  '1',  '2',  '2',  '3',  
 '1981',  '0',  '0',  '0',  '0',  '0',  '1',  '10.5',  '6', '13',  '150',  
 '60',  '190',  '90',  '145',  '85',  '0',  '0',  '2.3', '3',  '-9',  '-9',  
 '0',  '-9',  '-9',  '-9',  '-9',  '-9',  '-9',  '6',  '-9',  '-9',  '-9',  
 '2',  '16',  '1981',  '0',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '-9',  '1',  '-9',  '1',  
 '-9',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '-9',  '-9',  '0',  '-9',  
 '-9',  '-9',  '-9',  '-9',  '-9',  '-9',  '-9',  '-9',  '0',  '0',  '0',  
 '0',  'name',  '2',  '15964847',  '67',  '1',  '-9',  '-9',  '-9',  '-27',  
 '4',  '160',  '1',  '286',  '-9',  '40',  '40',  '0',  '0',  '1',  '2',  
 '3',  '5',  '1981',  '0',  '1',  '0',  '0',  '0',  '1',  '9.5',  '6', 
 '13',  '108',  '64',  '160',  '90',  '160',  '90',  '1',  '0',  '1.5',  
 '2',  '-9',  '-9',  '3',  '-9',  '-9',  '-9',  '-9',  '-9',  '-9',  '3',  
 '-9',  '-9',  '-9',  '2',  '5',  '1981',  '2',  '1',  '2',  '2',  '-9',  
 '2',  '-9',  '1',  '-9',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '-9',  
 '-9',  '0',  '-9',  '-9',  '-9',  '-9',  '-9',  '-9',  '-9',  '-9',  '-9',  
 '0',  '0',  '0',  '0',  'name']
```

How would I create 2 lists that split at value `'name'`? The index at the value `'name'` isn't always the same through the entire list, fyi.

Comment: use `my_list.index('name')` to get the index where you need to split...

Comment: what if there are multiple `name` in the list? do you want the split to be recursive?

Comment: As always, this is not a code-writing service. What have you tried?

Comment: I had tried things, but it never really got anywhere. I wrote a for loop to find the index of each occurence of 'name', but didn't think it was an optimal solution. Being clueless, I chose to ask here. Could have specified that I wanted a neater Pythonic solution in the post I guess.

Comment: At the risk of being redundant, I did look up other threads, but didn't find any matches. I wouldn't post a question without seeing what's out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To split the list on multiple `name` elements you can use `itertools.groupby()` from the standard modules:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> data = ['1', '15943882', '63', '1', '-9', '-9', '-9', '-27', '1', '145', '1', ...]
>>> [list(g) for k, g in it.groupby(data, lambda x: x=='name') if not k]
[['1', '15943882', '63', '1', '-9', '-9', '-9', '-27', '1', '145', ...
 ['2', '15964847', '67', '1', '-9', '-9', '-9', '-27', '4', '160', ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
idx = x.index('name')
(x[0:idx], x[idx+1:])
```

This would split on the first index of 'name'.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`split`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/split.html) function in the library `iteration_utilities` that could be useful in this context:

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import split
>>> l1, l2 = split(your_list, key='name', eq=True)
>>> l1
['1', '15943882', '63', '1', '-9', '-9', '-9', '-27', '1', '145', '1', 
 '233', '-9', '50', '20', '1', '0', '1', '2', '2', '3', '1981', '0', 
 '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '10.5', '6', '13', '150', '60', '190', '90', 
 '145', '85', '0', '0', '2.3', '3', '-9', '-9', '0', '-9', '-9', '-9', 
 '-9', '-9', '-9', '6', '-9', '-9', '-9', '2', '16', '1981', '0', '1', 
 '1', '1', '-9', '1', '-9', '1', '-9', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 
 '1', '-9', '-9', '0', '-9', '-9', '-9', '-9', '-9', '-9', '-9', '-9',
 '-9', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

Note that this deletes the `key` (in this case `'name'`) from the results.

The function is also able to split the list into multiple parts, if that's not wanted you can specify `maxsplit=1`.

Note: I'm the author of the library `iteration_utilities`. Just to mention it: It's also easy to implement this function in pure Python:

```
def split(iterable, delimiter):
    lst = []
    for item in iterable:
        if item == delimiter:
            yield lst
            lst = []
        else:
            lst.append(item)
    if lst:
        yield lst
```